# Noise on LT1624 with shutdown function

Tags: noise, nmos, switching-regulator

In the circuit bellow, based on an [LTC1624](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1624f.pdf), with the SHDN input low, the Ith/RUN pin is extremely noisy, with spikes dropping way below the 0.8V shutdown threshold. As a consequence, the circuit can't stand inrush currents (ARM Linux module.)

If I remove Q20 (a [PMBF170](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBF170.pdf),) it works like a charm - except of course the shutdown feature.

My conclusion is that the blocked NMOS Q20 is the cause of the noise. How can I fix this?

I added the [PMBF170](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMBF170.pdf) in LTSpice simulation, but it doesn't change anything.

[image: 24-3.3V converter]

Answer (score 1):

So, without PMBF170 it works, and with PMBF170 it doesn't.

Try a differential diagnosis approach to see if the FET is the problem, and if so, which characteristic of the FET is the problem.

Hypothesis: the regulator starts up when its power supply ramps up, but it can't start up when it is already powered. This can happen if it doesn't like the load capacitors, if there is too much inrush current, etc.

Test: Power the circuit (without PMBF170) and short Ith/Run to ground with your tweezers... this should shut down the regulator. Next, remove the short, and look at the output voltage with a scope. Does the regulator startup correctly? If so, the regulator is fine and the FET is guilty.

Hypothesis: FET capacitance wrecks the regulator compensation, since the pin is also used for that.

Test: replace the FET with a 30pF capacitor, which should correspond to its Cds value. If this makes the regulator misbehave (which is likely) then the FET's capacitance is the problem. Use a FET with lower capacitance, or a MMBT3904.

Other hypothesis:

The FET doesn't have a gate resistor and is driven by something that doesn't like capacitive loads.

The FET is driven by a noisy voltage which turns it on somewhat.

There was some leftover bits of solder or water soluble flux shorting stuff.

The layout is bad and the source of the FET is connected to a very noisy ground, like the bottom of D27. Or some of the switching noise from the DC-DC couples into its gate.

Comment: Without Q20, clean signal. With 22pF capacitor instead of Q20 (test Cds) : clean signal. Eventually, I fixed it with a 10K series resistor between the drain of Q20 and Ith/RUN. I guess that Q20 conducts somehow. The internal diode ? The source of Q20 is a clean 0V level.